# How to prevent adding data to a localhost database after refresh?

Tags: php

-3

I am currently trying to upload data to a database which I have successfully done. I then have it displaying on the editPage.php and have an option to delete any of the data that has been inputed into the database. The problem is, every time I delete the line of data from the database, my page refreshes and the same data is then reentered back into the database. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my editPage.php which allows for data to be inserted, viewed and deleted.

```
<?php
session_start();

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "skilltask2");

if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] == false) {
    header('Location: skillsTask2.php');
}
if(isset($_POST['content']) || isset($_POST['header']) || isset($_POST['image'])){
    $displayText = $_POST['content'];
    $displayHeader = $_POST['header'];
    $dir="images/";
    $file=$dir.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `content` (`image`) VALUES ('$file')";
    if(strlen($displayText)>0){
        $query = "INSERT INTO `content` (`text`, `header`, `image`) VALUES ('$displayText', '$displayHeader', '$file')";
    }

    if (mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
        echo '<script>alert("Title, Text and Image has been uploaded to database")</script>';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="editPage.css">
    <script>
        function deleteContent(id,header) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "processDelete.php?id="+id, true);
            xhr.send();
            alert("You have deleted "+header);
            location.reload();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container" style="width:25vw;">
        <h3 align="center">Update and Insert Headers, Text and Images</h3>
        <br>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <input type="text" name="header" required />
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3>Text</h3>
            <input type="text" name="content" required />
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3>Image</h3>
            <input type="file" name="image" required />
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="all" value="Upload All" />
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <?php
            echo "<a href=\"skillsTask2.php\">Logout</a>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
        <?php
                    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "skilltask2");
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY `id` DESC";  
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {  
                        $theimage = $row['image'];
                        $theheader = $row['header'];
                        $thetext = $row['text'];
                        $id = $row['id'];
                         echo "<div id='card'>
                                <img src=\"".$theimage."\" >
                                <div id='cardHeader'>
                                    <b>$theheader</b><br>$thetext
                                </div>
                                <button onclick=deleteContent($id,'$theheader')>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        ";
                        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my processDelete.php page which deletes the lines of code from the database.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "skilltask2");
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM content WHERE id=$id"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die ( mysqli_error());
?>
```

Hopefully you can help. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess the data you're adding is in the query string and 'location.reload()' is reloading the page with the same query string params. You could strip the query string from that I'd guess. You probably also need to wait for your XMLHttpRequest to complete to say that the record is deleted - they're asynchronous by default - and check the response too.

Comment: And this isn't obviously WordPress to me?

Comment: Don't worry. I fixed it using header("Refresh:0"); in the editPage.php

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with using `header("Refresh:0");`

This allows the page to be refreshed immediately after the `if` statement has been processed, allowing the page to not resend the data that was inserted before.